# Laravel 5.1 ajax based login/registration using Auth controller?

Tags: jquery, ajax, authentication, laravel-5.1

I am learning laravel framework.
I have some question while learning authenticatation.

I have tried login and registrartion by refering laravel [Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication).

Now want to make login and registartion using ajax.
My  question is do I need to write new controller and method for login and registration because need return data in json format to display validation message or redirect after login.
**OR**
Is there any way We can use same AUthentication controller and method to work with ajax.
Please suggest appropriate solution ?

Comment: No you don't have to use separate controller for this.  If you can dig into the given code, you can return the responses as json. That is : return Response::json(['success'=>true]);

Comment: Using default login/authentication will required to modify core methods. you can you use Laravel default methods and also can create your own ajax based authentication.

Comment: @Qazi so basically i have to touch the code of core files of laravel, right ?

Comment: @JilsonThomas: Without writing separate controller. How we can handle error validation with ajax ?

Comment: @Kango as per my understanding, it would be better to use your own controller for Ajax based. don't modify core files, because if you ever try to update your Laravel version, then core modified files will be updated also, means your written code will be replaced to its factory default code

Comment: What kind of Ajax based auth are you doing? I recently used Ajax with laravel and ended up retrieving the csrf-token from the page and used that as the Ajax auth token and all was good. This only works if you don't need external users to use the Ajax based auth however.